# Compare dataframe columns by another column elements and compute accuracy percentage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have two dataframes of unequal lengths, **df1** & **df2**.

The first dataframe **df1** looks like this :

```
id | a   |  b  |  c  |  d
--------------------------
i1 | 1,2 |  0  | Nan |  3
i2 |  1  |  4  |  2  | 0,3
i3 |  0  |  1  | 2,3 | Nan
```

And the second dataframe **df2** looks like this :

```
id | a   |  b  |  c  |  d
--------------------------
i5 | 0,3 |  1  | 2,4 | Nan
i2 |  1  |  4  |  2  |  0
i3 |  0  |  1  | 2,3 | Nan
i4 |  0  |  1  | 2,3 | Nan
i1 |  1  |  0  | Nan |  3
```

Both dataframes have the same columns names; **a, b, c & d**. They might have the same elements in the column **id** but not necessarily in the same order.

Now for every common id number in the column **id**, I want to compare all the columns **a, b, c & d** values and compute an accuracy percentage.

For example, let's look at the id number **i1**, in df1 the values in column **a** for this id number are 1,2 but in df2, with the same id number **i1**, the values in column **a** are 1. So the value 2 is missing and therefore the accuracy should be something like 50%. This will be repeated for every column and for every row. If the id number in df2 does not exist in df1 or the opposite it should be ignored. I want to compute the final accuracy percentage and be able to visualize the elements that matches and the ones that do not.

To compare column a, I have tried something like this :

```
new_df2 = df2[df2.id.isin(df1.id)]

acc = (df1.sort_values('id')['a'].reset_index()==new_df2.sort_values('id')['a'].reset_index()).mean()
```

I am not sure if this is correct or if it's the best way to do it. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Your best bet is to merge the two dataframes by column 'id' and then do the comparison. I did not understand the comparison mechanism you are after

Comment: new_df2 = df2[df2.id.isin(df1.id)] 
With this, df2 will keep only the id numbers that exist in df1.
For example, for the id number i1, in df1 the values in column a for this id number are 1,2 but in df2, with the same id number i1, the values in column a are 1. So the value 2 is missing here and therefore I should have an accuracy of 50% or something like this.

Comment: This explanation is not enough. please provide expected output to your tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom function to compute the [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), convert each item to `set`, align the two DataFrames and apply it vectorially:

```
from numpy import vectorize

@vectorize
def compare(a, b):
    A = set(map(int, a.split(','))) if isinstance(a, str) else {a}
    B = set(map(int, b.split(','))) if isinstance(b, str) else {b}
    return len(A&B)/len(A|B) # multiply by 100 for %

tmp = df1.set_index('id')

out = (pd.DataFrame(compare(tmp, df2.set_index('id').reindex_like(tmp)),
                    index=tmp.index, columns=tmp.columns)
         .reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   id    a    b    c    d
0  i1  0.5  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  i2  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.5
2  i3  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: That's a great idea ! Thanks !

Comment: @Mejdi you're welcome, I forgot to convert the strings to int though, see update ;)

Comment: Or keep everything as string: `A = set(str(a).split(',')) ; B = set(str(b).split(','))`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks !